# How to import a generic stabilizer code in stim

Tags: programming, error-correction, simulation, stabilizer-code, stim

I just started using [stim](https://github.com/quantumlib/Stim) to simulate the performance of quantum error correcting codes. I hope this is the right place to ask questions about the subject. The
[example code](https://github.com/quantumlib/Stim/blob/main/doc/getting_started.ipynb)
with the repetition code and depolarizing channel worked fine. Now I want to try one of my codes and the same channel. How would I import my code into stim? I can write the stabilizers as an $m \times n$ array ($m$ stabilizers, $n$ qubits) with entries from $(0,1,2,3)$; this seems like the most straight forward way. $(0=I,1=X,2=Z,3=Y)$.

For example, for the $[[5,1,3]]$ code $S:=[[1,2,2,1,0],[0,1,2,2,1],[1,0,1,2,2],[2,1,0,1,2]];$

Is this the preferred way? Do I also need to specify the logicals or destabilizers (I have these for some codes but maybe stim calculates them from the stabilizer...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stim is very much a circuit focused simulator. It speaks quantum operations, not stabilizer configurations, so you have to convert your table of stabilizers into a stabilizer circuit. This is a bit inconvenient, but ultimately makes Stim much more flexible as a tool (e.g. it has no issues with gauge codes or non-foliated codes).

The "proper" thing for you to do would be to find the encoding circuit for your code and put that into Stim. A fallback strategy could be to use the [`MPP` instruction](https://github.com/quantumlib/Stim/wiki/Stim-v1.5-Gate-Reference#MPP) (Measure Pauli Product) to measure the stabilizers of the code. For example, here is a circuit that projects into your given code, applies single qubit depolarizing noise, re-measures the stabilizers, and produces detection events based on whether or not each stabilizer was flipped:

```
MPP X0*Z1*Z2*X3 X1*Z2*Z3*X4 X0*X2*Z3*Z4 Z0*X1*X3*Z4
DEPOLARIZE1(0.001) 0 1 2 3 4
MPP X0*Z1*Z2*X3 X1*Z2*Z3*X4 X0*X2*Z3*Z4 Z0*X1*X3*Z4
DETECTOR rec[-1] rec[-5]
DETECTOR rec[-2] rec[-6]
DETECTOR rec[-3] rec[-7]
DETECTOR rec[-4] rec[-8]
```

In python, you append MPP instructions like this:

```
circuit.append_operation("MPP", [
    stim.target_x(0),
    stim.target_combiner(),
    stim.target_z(1),
    stim.target_combiner(),
    stim.target_z(2),
    stim.target_combiner(),
    stim.target_x(3),
])
```

(The target combiners (`*`) are needed because you can give multiple products to `MPP`.)

Measuring the stabilizers will randomly project the system into their +1 or -1 eigenstates. If for some reason you **need** the +1 eigenstate you can do a conditional Pauli correction, e.g. `CNOT rec[-1] 3` would apply an X gate to qubit 3 if the most recent measurement was True (presumably indicating the associated stabilizer measurement said the system was in the -1 eigenstate). The [`stim.TableauSimulator.measure_kickback` method](https://github.com/quantumlib/Stim/wiki/Stim-v1.5-Python-API-Reference#stimtableausimulatormeasure_kickbackself-target-int---tuple) is a bit technical but can be used for finding a Pauli correction that won't ruin the other stabilizers of the state.

Anyways, *ideally* you would know an encoding circuit already. Otherwise, Stim provides a few basic tools like `MPP` and`measure_kickback` to help discover some of the pieces of such a circuit, but doesn't currently have an end-to-end "give me a well formed list of stabilizers and I give you a circuit" helper method.

Comment: I think I can get the encoding circuit for most codes; so I'll move in that direction if there's no better way. There are algorithms to put the stabilizers into canonical form and then derive the encoding circuit from that; there's a fair amount of details that I was hoping to avoid with complications if you have redundant stabilizers...maybe someone know of a separate package that performs this step. Assuming I can get the encoding circuit, is the decoder used in the repetition code example generic enough to handle an arbitrary code?

Comment: @unknown No, most codes can't be decoded by a matching decoder which is what [the repetition code example](https://github.com/quantumlib/Stim/blob/main/doc/getting_started.ipynb) uses. Stim is not a decoding library; even the rep code example is using pymatching to do the decoding not Stim itself. Stim's decoding story focuses on providing building block tools (`stim.Circuit.detector_error_model` and `stim.Circuit.compile_detector_sampler` in this case) that are useful for getting configuration data and detection event data into a decoder.

Comment: oh that's too bad...I was encouraged by how quickly you were able to simulate the honeycomb code but I guess many parts of that sim are not part of stim

Comment: @unknown The honeycomb also has the surprising property that it can be decoded by matching, so I could use PyMatching for it. If it had required eg. a color code decoder I definitely would have struggled more, since I'm not familiar with those. Stim would still have been able to give me measurement results, and detection events, and a detector error model (corresponding to a hypergraph instead of a graph), but I wouldn't have had a ready tool for decoding.

Comment: @unknown Having a decoder that could efficiently decode any stabilizer code sure would be magical. But seems a bit... utterly insanely difficult.

Comment: you're right...decoder design is difficult (efficient or even implementable ones much more so). That being said, some decoders are more generic than others. There are generic decoders for erasure channel. For small codes, there are also generic decoders that won't scale for larger codes. I would only use these to calibrate the simulation environment. In general I almost always have difficulty duplicating published results because of the incredibly lax rules for describing channels, decoders,...At this point if I can't duplicate the results myself then I don't beleive what's being claimed.